# XML key/keyref across multiple XML instances

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, key, keyref

is it possible to validate key/keyref across multiple XML instances. Example: xsd1 defines a schema and namespace for a list of DataTypes, each DataType has a unique identifier ID which is defined as a keyref. xsd2 defines a list of entities, that shall use the IDs from xsd1. In the XML authoring software Oxygen e.g. the xsd-referencing with key/keyref across the two namespaces works, but I do not manage to create a validation scenario like:
"Field X in XML2 (validated against xsd2) can only contain values from the fields ID in XML1(validated against xsd1)"

Is this possible in XML-authoring state at all? Or would I always have to implement that validation manually? Which wouldn't be a big deal, but it might be helpful to provide users with a sophisticated authoring-validation-toolbox if such exists.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do it with XSD. You could do it across documents using Schematron. Now, Schematron equivalent for key/keyref is not that declarative as its XSD counterpart, but nonetheless doable. Have a look at [this article](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/12/converting-xml-schemas-to-sche.html) for details... keep in mind that it is meant to be a generic solution to the key/unique/keyref construct, you could probably do it simpler for your particular case.

Comment: Thank you for this information. But to make sure I'm right about schematron: The whole XML is still not checked/validated "on the fly" / live while writing the XML files, right? There is nothing like IntelliSense for XML authoring, that looks in specific XML files to validate and/or suggest the XML while writing, right? I'm asking because I want to find the best suite of tools for users who have to create XML which is compliant with my schemas. They still have to write all XML and run it through some validation of my system which checks if everything is valid?!

Comment: Of course you can do it "on the fly"; but then, what authoring software do you have in mind? Are you asking whether something such as Oxygen can do it, or in general, something that you wish to build yourself? The latter could be relatively easy to build... a proprietary editor that is based on open technologies to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear on that. My question was, if something like this already exists. I'm aware that implementing it would not be such a big deal.

Comment: You mean as in exists in some sort of API? Java? .Net? Not that I am aware of.

Comment: No, does a tool / toolsuite exist, which supports this? But I anticipate it doesn't.

Comment: I am not aware of any tool that would do Schematron "on the fly"; another problem typical to Schematron is that it won't give you a line number and column/character position, as typically seen with XSD-aware processors.